Get cookies in _document.js (nextjs) works fine on localhost but not in production or just once and only on Safari Browser
The console.log in getInitialProps is printed on localhost and with the correct value on every refresh. But in production in Chrome it is always empty and is only printed randomly. In Safari it printed once with the correct value and then never again.
This is my cookie component and how I set cookies via react-cookies-consent:
// components/ExtendedCookieConsent.js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CookieConsent, { Cookies } from "react-cookie-consent";

const ExtendedCookieConsent = () => {
  const [appsflyerConsent, setAppsflyerConsent] = useState(true);
  const [mixpanelConsent, setMixpanelConsent] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter();



  const handleAccept = () => {
    Cookies.set(
      "myAppCookieConsent",
      { appsflyer: appsflyerConsent, mixpanel: mixpanelConsent },
      {
        expires:
          appsflyerConsent === true && mixpanelConsent === true ? 365 : 1,
        path: "/",
        domain: ".mydomain.com",
        sameSite: "Lax",
        secure: true,
      }
    );
    router.reload();
  };

  const handleDecline = () => {
    Cookies.set(
      "myAppCookieConsent",
      { appsflyer: false, mixpanel: false },
      {
        expires: 1,
        path: "/",
        domain: ".mydomain.com",
        sameSite: "Lax",
        secure: true,
      }
    );
    router.reload();
  };

  return (
    <CookieConsent
      location="bottom"
      buttonText="Speichern"
      declineButtonText="All ablehnen"
      cookieName="myAppCookieConsent"
      style={{
        background: "#454545cf",
        backdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
        WebkitBackdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
        padding: "10px",
        display: "table-column",
      }}
      declineButtonStyle={{
        background: "#45454500",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        color: "white",
        cursor: "pointer",
      }}
      buttonStyle={{
        background: "#51d198",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        color: "#1b1b1b",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        cursor: "pointer",
      }}
      enableDeclineButton
      onAccept={handleAccept}
      onDecline={handleDecline}
    >
      <div>...</div>
    </CookieConsent>
  );
};

export default ExtendedCookieConsent;

And this is how I read them using nookies.js in _document.js after user sets consent and initiates a refresh of the page:
// pages/_document.js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { parseCookies } from "nookies";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    // Parsing cookies from the request
    const cookies = parseCookies(ctx);
    const cookieConsent = cookies.myAppCookieConsent
      ? JSON.parse(cookies.myAppCookieConsent)
      : {};
    console.log("CookieConsent : " + JSON.stringify(cookieConsent, 0, 2));
    return { ...initialProps, cookieConsent };
  }

  render() {
    <Html>
     <Head>
     {appsflyerConsent && (
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: ` my appsflyer script `,
          }}
        />
      )}
     </Head>
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
  }
}

export default MyDocument;

